# Eclipse debug setting

Tags: android

This is a question about Eclipse debug setting.

I was learning to debug in Eclipse

I was trying to debug for a value as directed in the link- [Android Eclipse Debugging: Getting Intermediate Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004341/android-eclipse-debugging-getting-intermediate-values)

Initially - in the debug window, the tabs - **"Variables", "Breakpoints"** was there. I was trying to get"Expressions" tab.

But in between I opted for some - Quick Debug' or something. The suddenly everything changed.

**How can revert the view - so that I will get "Variables", "Breakpoints" tabs.**

**Presently it shows like**
[image]

**I want to switch it back to**

[image]

pls help

---

After resetting - the Tabs -Variables, Breakpoints is not coming back...

Actually what I want is to get the value of the variables while debugging.

In screen-shot attached (below) - I want to get the value of txt1
[image]

Comment: Debug your app again. It will come back. Use F6 to move to the next line while debugging and F9 to resume program flow(It will help you to move to the next break point if there are any)

Comment: if it won't just try: Window->Reset Perspective

Answer (score 0):

You can use Window -> Reset perspective, as tenhouse said, or you could customize it for your needs, you can chose whatever you need in Window -> show view section of the menu.

Comment: Pl see the new screen-shot attached & comments.                  After resetting - the Tabs -Variables, Breakpoints is not coming back...

Actually what I want is to get the value of the variables while debugging.

In screen-shot attached (below) - I want to get the value of txt1

Comment: You can use Window-> Show View -> Variables, but if you want to check the values of variables during debugging, the simplest way is to move your cursor over the variable you are interested in when it is already given value. When the debugging reaches line "integer j = ..." and the execution stops, move your mouse over txt1 and see its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Put your mouse on the variable, and you will see the value of it floated when debugging.